# What to do with non-answers by low rep users that I have no opinion on

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I know the generally accepted action for non-answers is to flag the answer as "not an answer", and then to add it as a comment to the question or flag / vote on the question (in case of duplicates) oneself if you agree with the answer, or do nothing more if you disagree.

What should I do when I neither agree nor disagree (i.e. have no opinion on the matter)?

As an example, let's say a user simply posts a link to another question as an answer. This would be better suited as a duplicate flag. But I'm not really sure whether or not it's actually a duplicate.

Similarly, a user may comment on the question, but I may not have sufficient knowledge in the domain to know if it's applicable.

I don't particularly want to just comment myself as:

- I won't be able to justify the action.
- I don't want to risk damaging others' opinion of myself by making an illogical comment / flag / vote.

So, what should I do if I find myself in this scenario?

Perhaps add some sort of "this is not my comment" indicator? If so, any suggestions?

Voting to close as a duplicate is fairly low-risk (given that 4 other people will have to agree first) - should I do that where applicable (and perhaps change the comment as per above indicator)? This would be a different story if I didn't have 3k reputation (or if another flag is applicable, which I don't really see as a possibility) - in this case it may negatively affect my flagging history.

Comment: Generally speaking, a link to another SO post as an answer (without adding anything substantial) is either a duplicate post or an incorrect answer.  So a downvote would seem appropriate.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, the answer should go, but I'm wondering whether I should add a comment to the question or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address your first example:

> ...let's say a user simply posts a link to another question as an answer. This would be better suited as a duplicate flag. But I'm not really sure whether or not it's actually a duplicate.

A link to another question should *always* be a comment in my opinion, so I always convert these whether I think it's a really a duplicate or not.  I'll close one of the questions if I agree that they're the same, but I'll just leave them alone if I don't know enough about the subject.

> Similarly, a user may comment on the question, but I may not have sufficient knowledge in the domain to know if it's applicable.

If you're not sure, it's ok to do nothing.  I'll often leave a post for other mods or users to handle if I don't know anything about the subject, or if I can't tell for certain that a post is definitively *not an answer*.

Comment: For the second example, "do nothing" *in addition* to flagging it, or *just* do nothing?

Comment: @Dukeling I'd just do nothing if you're really not sure. If it's that borderline a case, then there's probably no harm in just leaving things alone.